# PHP update page for forms

Tags: php, mysql, forms, updating

Im trying to create a updating page for my form application, so that users can change whats in the forms. The problem is, I keep getting errors such as:

Notice: Undefined index at line 72

> $PersonId = $_GET['PersonId'];

```
<?php


    function connect_db() { 


    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_lab2');


    if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
        echo "Fel vid inställning av teckentabell utf8: %s\n". $mysqli->error;
    } else {

    }

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Misslyckades att ansluta till MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    return $mysqli;
}


    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>     
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['spara'])){


        $PersonId = $_POST['PersonId'];
        $Fnamn = $_POST['Fnamn'];
        $Enamn = $_POST['Enamn'];
        $Gatuadress = $_POST['Gatuadress'];
        $Postnummer = $_POST['Postnummer']; 
        $Postadress = $_POST['Postadress']; 
        $Telefon = $_POST['Telefon'];   
        $Epost = $_POST['Epost'];   

        $sql = "UPDATE person SET Fnamn='$Fnamn', Enamn='$Enamn', Gatuadress='$Gatuadress', Postnummer='$Postnummer', Postadress='$Postadress',
        Telefon='$Telefon', Epost='$Epost' WHERE PersonId=$PersonId";


        if($mysqli = connect_db()) {

        $mysqli->query($sql);
        print_r($mysqli->error);
        }




        echo "Personen är nu ändrad<br />";
        echo "<a href='person.php'>Tillbaka till listningssidan</a>";
    }

    else{


        $PersonId = $_GET['PersonId'];


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE PersonId=$PersonId";


        if($mysqli = connect_db()) {

        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        print_r($mysqli->error);
        }
        $myRow = $result->fetch_array()

        ?>

        <form action="update_person.php?PersonId=<?php echo $PersonId ?>" method="post">
            <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                <tr><td>Person</td><td><input type="text" name="PersonId" value="<? echo $myRow[0]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Förnamn</td><td><input type="text" name="Fnamn" value="<? echo $myRow[1]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Efternamn</td><td><input type="text" name="Enamn" value="<? echo $myRow[2]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Gatuadress</td><td><input type="text" name="Gatuadress" value="<? echo $myRow[3]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Postnummer</td><td><input type="text" name="Postnummer" value="<? echo $myRow[4]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Postadress</td><td><input type="text" name="Postadress" value="<? echo $myRow[5]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Telefon</td><td><input type="text" name="Telefon" value="<? echo $myRow[6]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Epost</td><td><input type="text" name="Epost" value="<? echo $myRow[7] ?>" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="spara" value="Spara" />
            </table>
        </form>
        <?php
        }
        ?>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add a check before requesting the $_GET, do it by adding isset() around your $_GET to prevent this error.

Comment: @Tosfera: You should make that an answer :-).

Comment: First of all, it's not a error its warning and you can turn it of by add to the start of your script 1 line

Comment: By doing so I get this error message @Tosfera Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: You'll indeed get another error, sec. Let me update the code for you.

Comment: Also, make sure you don't allow random user input like that in your code, please consider using mysqli_escape_string to avoid sql injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    function connect_db() { 
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_lab2');

        if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
            echo "Fel vid inställning av teckentabell utf8: %s\n". $mysqli->error;
        } 

        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Misslyckades att ansluta till MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }

        return $mysqli;
    }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>     
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        if ( isset ( $_POST['spara'] ) ) {
            $PersonId = $_POST['PersonId'];
            $Fnamn = $_POST['Fnamn'];
            $Enamn = $_POST['Enamn'];
            $Gatuadress = $_POST['Gatuadress'];
            $Postnummer = $_POST['Postnummer']; 
            $Postadress = $_POST['Postadress']; 
            $Telefon = $_POST['Telefon'];   
            $Epost = $_POST['Epost'];   

            if ( $mysqli = connect_db() ) {
                $sql = "UPDATE person SET Fnamn='$Fnamn', Enamn='$Enamn', Gatuadress='$Gatuadress', Postnummer='$Postnummer', Postadress='$Postadress', Telefon='$Telefon', Epost='$Epost' WHERE PersonId=". $mysqli->escape_string($PersonId);
                $mysqli->query ( $sql );
                print_r ( $mysqli->error );
            }

            echo "Personen är nu ändrad<br />";
            echo "<a href='person.php'>Tillbaka till listningssidan</a>";
        } else {
            if ( isset ( $_GET['PersonId'] ) ) {
                if ( $mysqli = connect_db() ) {
                    $PersonId = $_GET['PersonId'];
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE PersonId=$PersonId";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
                    print_r ( $mysqli->error );
                    $myRow = $result->fetch_array();
                }
            }
    ?>

            <form action="update_person.php?PersonId=<?php echo $PersonId ?>" method="post">
                <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                    <tr><td>Person</td><td><input type="text" name="PersonId" value="<? echo $myRow[0]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Förnamn</td><td><input type="text" name="Fnamn" value="<? echo $myRow[1]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Efternamn</td><td><input type="text" name="Enamn" value="<? echo $myRow[2]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Gatuadress</td><td><input type="text" name="Gatuadress" value="<? echo $myRow[3]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Postnummer</td><td><input type="text" name="Postnummer" value="<? echo $myRow[4]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Postadress</td><td><input type="text" name="Postadress" value="<? echo $myRow[5]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Telefon</td><td><input type="text" name="Telefon" value="<? echo $myRow[6]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Epost</td><td><input type="text" name="Epost" value="<? echo $myRow[7]; ?>" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="spara" value="Spara" />
                </table>
            </form>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

That should do.

Comment: I get this error when i use this code: Notice: Undefined variable: PersonId in C:\xampp\htdocs\labb2\update_person.php on line 74

Line 74 is: $sql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE PersonId=$PersonId";

Comment: It shouldn't reach that code, it's protected by the isset ( ). Could you replace the code, again, with my code and use ctrl + F5 to get a hard refresh?

Comment: I managed to get rid of a spelling mistake on my form and I refreshed the page. Now I get this error on most of the solutions that have been posted including yours: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in "filelocation"on line 80 @Tosfera

Comment: move `$myRow = $result->fetch_array()` into the `if ( $mysqli = connect_db()) { }`. You're now trying to retrieve an array from what might be an unavailable result. :)

Comment: Also, you're missing a `;` behind the fetch_array()

Comment: I'm sorry, I suck at this. How would this look like? I get more errors when I move it.. @Tosfera

Comment: I got another error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' on line 102. This is the PHP code below the form ( <?php } ?> ). @Tosfera

Comment: What is line 102? It's quite confusing because you changed your code. :P

Comment: `<? echo $myRow[7] ?>`, you're missing a `;`. mind try and use that to fix it?

Comment: Nice catch. I fixed it but nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the entire new code again? There must be something wrong.

Comment: So did I, also cleaned it up a bit.. added a mysqli_escape_string too, so people don't inject your database.

Answer (score 0):

Add isset condition:

It might be the condition that `$_GET['PersonId']` is not getting set.

```
$PersonId = isset($_GET['PersonId']) ? $_GET['PersonId'] : '';
```

Also, if this value is blank or not set, there is no use of the code following it.

Better way use if condition like:

```
if (isset($_GET['PersonId']) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE PersonId=$PersonId";
  // The form code
}
```

Comment: I get this error when I use this code: 

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in "file location" on line 80 

Line 80 is: $myRow = $result->fetch_array()

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the GET parameters are set before using them in your script.

You could do:

```
if (!isset($_GET['param'])) {
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all its not error its warning
and you can remove that by add to the start of your script this line (ignore warnings)

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

And as has been said here you can check to see if the var was initialize
like that

```
if(isset($_GET['PersonId']) {
//do something with PersonId
}
```

Comment: Ya, good boy. Turn off the errors and create bugs for a guy who's new in PHP. Not the smartest person èh?

Comment: As I said the best practise is to check but i'm just showing you can do something else. In fact it is best to do both when you release something because you will never be able to catch all off your mistake in complex software

Comment: You and I both know that this isn't for commercial use, he would've protected everything with mysql_escape_string and things like that. But oh well, error_reporting is a nice thing to know. just not for educational things.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you have the form in an else clause. You POST the variable through a form which is only shown if that very variable is in a GET request. Is this added to your URL?

That error is born because `$_GET['PersonId']` looks for the `PersonId` parameter in your URL and does not find it.

Everyone who has answers with `isset` in it is on the right path also. Use that to properly guard your code.